# Virtual Box Ubuntu Server 18.04 TWO Network Adapters

Tags: server

Hello i tried to make an Ubuntu Virtual Server with 2 Network Adapters

In Virtual Box i added the First Network Adapter with NAT and the second Network Adapter with Host Only.

Now in Ubuntu i edited the "/etc/network/interfaces" to

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback 
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

when i now use "ifconfig -a" only enp0s3 has an ip address

what am i doing wrong so that enp0s8 will get an IP Address too?

Answer (score 1):

The VirtualBox connected adaptor does not have DHCP enabled by default. You either need to statically assign an IP address or in the VirtualBox management interface turn on the DHCP assignment feature.

Comment: In Host only Settings -> DHCP is activated

Comment: Did you assign an address range to the DHCP server in the VirtualBox manager interface?

Comment: Its from 192.168.56.3 to 192.168.56.254
DHCP Server Adress: 192.168.56.2

Comment: Do you have any vm's with working host only interfaces?

Comment: No thats the only one. If i set the Host Only Network as 1 Adapter its working fine, but only the Host Only Adapter

Comment: Okay, wow, that's odd. Sounds like your doing what your should. Check with VirtualBox to see if this is a known issue. Not sure what else to try at this point.